# styled-components: server side rendering

Tags: nginx, server-side, styled-components

https://github.com/ayroblu/ssr-create-react-app-v2

My basic app structure is based on the repository linked above.

And I'm using styled-components v2.

Also, my app is deployed on Vultr server, ubuntu 17.x, using nginx.

problem:

When I run my app locally, it works as I expected.

However, when I run my app on the server, it's successfully rendered but without styles.

[image: my app without style]

I tried to read documents about "server-side-rendering" in styled-components but I don't think I get it.

And what I found was that my app running on the server doesn't contain global styles injected in Head tag.

[image: empty head]

Comment: your question needs further information as it is, it's very vague.

Do you have any console errors? Can you include code snippets of how you are using styled components? preferably on codepen so we can easily play around with your code

Comment: Did you get the answer. I am also having similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567131/server-rendered-react-component-class-name-automatically-changed-causing-styling