# Server rendered React component class name automatically changed causing styling issue

Tags: reactjs, heroku, hapi.js, server-side-rendering

I am using React 16 in my personal project (https://github.com/sachinjha1/react-redux-hapi-fullstack-starter/blob/master/package.json).

I implemented SSR which works fine on my local. When i test the same app on Heroku all my styling are missing. When i did view source of server rendered html then i noticed that class names are different when rendered from Heroku.

Heroku App URL -> https://raxpi.herokuapp.com/
In above heroku url in browser if you check view source you can see that class names are like C2, C6 etc... On my local i can see those class names exactly from Material UI. Because if this difference app in Heroku looks off style. Not sure how its happening.

Comment: there is no stylesheet in your page, please check how are you importing css  in your component - there is no <style> tag in your html.

Comment: I am using material-ui. And it works fine in local with all styling.

Comment: i found yesterdaty that material ui in itself changes class names based on Node Environment. So for now i hardcoded node_env to development then it works fine in heroku now. BTW heroku was setting node env to production by default.

Comment: good to know this...